# Remote Reboot an Encrypted Disk Ubuntu Server?

Tags: reboot, remote

I've got a small ubuntu server running the LAMP stack that uses an encrypted disk. I would like to know if it's possible to reboot it remotely. Currently I have to be physically present at the machine to enter in the passphrase to mount the volume.

I imagine there might be a way to set up some kind of autorunning script that runs during boot that can enter in the password for me, and then deletes this script.

Is this possible?

Comment: The lamp server only starts after login?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this will help? Looks to be using ssh for the operation.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot